# Raise a Text box event when fourth digit is entered

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am working on a c# windows forms application and I have a text box which accepts a maximum of four character for which I am trying to raise am event when fourth character.

I tried to include it in `KeyPress` event but to raise the event I had to press a key after all the four characters are entered

```
private void txtFourC_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 if ( txtFourC.TextLength == 4)
    {
       //code here
    }
 }
```

Is there a better way to do this may be other than `Key_Press`

Comment: Change your condition to `== 3`??

Answer (score 3):

To limit the maximum number of characters that users can type or paste into the `TextBox`, it's enough to set [`MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

If you don't want to limit the user, but you want to be notified when the user entered more than 4 characters, handle [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and check for [`TextLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.textlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property to know length of text in the control.

Comment: This is the best way to handle it, set the MaxLength and don't wory about keypress events.

Comment: @Dev Was the post what you were looking for? :)

Answer (score 0):

Or use the event to f.e. jump to the next field after the 4th digit is typed.
So use the TextChanged event and check for TextLength property to know length of text in the control and activate the next field.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to restrict input to maximum 4 characters then its best to set MaxLength property. `txtFourC.MaxLength=4`

However, if you want to show message when 4th character is typed in then you may use KeyUp event instead KeyPress.

```
private void txtFourC_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(txtFourC.Text.Length ==4)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Reached max length");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtFourC_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(txtFourC.Text.Length == 4)
    {
        //do your control here.
    }
}
```